# Laravel 5.1 rename project

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, rename

What is the best solution if I want to rename my laravel 5.1 project, I just tried to rename one but it did not work properly got some errors.

Are there some kind of steps one has to do to rename a laravel project?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should use `php artisan app:name` command to rename your app. It will change namespace in all project files for you. This is the only right way to rename your app.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#after-installation

Comment: is there also a way to rollback this

Comment: @JohnDoesLegacy, if you ran `php artisan app:name` command and now you want return everything back, just run `php artisan app:name App`

Comment: do you mean with app the old project name

Comment: that does not work anymore appserviceprovider not found

Comment: It seems you've also changed something manually. Just tried to rename an app and rename it back to `App`, it works just fine (Laravel 5.2). If you're using Git, just checkout old commit. If not, try to remember what did you change manually and try to repair it.

Comment: hmm ok nevertheless I'll give you a tick, Thanks!

Comment: if you get `ReflectionException error that class App\Console\Kernel can't be found` - `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 8):

From laravel version 5.3^ there is a function to call the app name

```
config('app.name');
```

You can change the default name 'Laravel' inside this file

```
config/app.php

'name' => 'Laravel',
```

And also inside .env file

APP_NAME=Laravel

Comment: This is what I was looking for. FYI If you're using `artisan serve` you will need to relaunch it

Answer (score 5):

I just recommend to:

1. go to .env file at APP-NAME =
2. put your desired name in "" (double quotes)
3. restart your server

And you're done.

Comment: "restart your server" - the most important notice when dealing with HTTP requests :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change your project name using the following command:

```
php artisan app:name your_git_name\your_app_name
```